# Deploy Spring MVS project on Ubuntu Server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2, web-deployment, ubuntu-server

I have an Ubuntu Server virtual machine on Amazon EC2. I want to deploy a Spring MVC project on it. As a result of my searching I found that this is possible but how? What steps should I go through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I build a runnable jar file with maven and send it to my EC2 machine with scp. Then I just run the jar file and it works.